# In C#, do all static variables get initialized before the main() method is called?

Tags: c#, .net, static, .net-assembly, static-members

The ones I am particularly concerned about are:

- static variables in classes that are defined in referenced/dependency classes, contained in external DLLs. In my example, none of the types in that third party assembly is reference until later in the program. (let's say 5 min into execution).

Will the static variables of that third-party assembly only be loaded then?

Thanks,
rui

Comment: If i understand the [C# Language Specification correctly](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), then static variables can not be just loaded - if they are referenced, they will be also initialized (look at paragraphs (in that order) 5.1.1, 5.2 and 10.12):A static variable comes into existence before execution of the static constructor (§10.12) for its containing type, and ceases to exist when the associated application domain ceases to exist. **and** ..the following events to occur within an application domain: 
Any of the static members of the class are referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to C# spec which says:

> If a static constructor exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class. The example

whiteout a static constructor you can not predict exactly when a static variable is initialized but they are guaranteed to be initialized before their first use. but for sure they are not initialized before you reference their assemblies

Answer (score 1):

All static fields are initialized before they are first used. This can be done by a type initializer (static constructor) explicitly declared or implicitly provided by the compiler. Static fields that do not have a value assigned in the class declaration will be initialized to the default value of their corresponding type.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if your static fields are object references whose constructors may throw exceptions:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo() { throw new Exception("boom"); }
}
class Bar
{
    private static Foo baz = new Foo();
    public Bar()
    {
        //trying to create a Bar will throw TypeInitializationException
    }
    public static void BarNone()
    {
        //trying to call a static method on Bar will throw TypeInitializationException
    }
}
```

You'll get a TypeInitializationException when Bar is first used (either constructed or when a static method on Bar is called), as shown above.